# How to change content of viewholder item based on observable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, rx-java2

In a reycler list, I have an Viewholder in which there is a button.
The text of a button is based on a variable if user is verified.
Now on click of user can be verified. a dialog is opened, user gets verified. After user is verified, i am updating sharedpreference boolean.
I have an observable on sharedpreference. How do i change/update viewholder items?
After verifying, i want to update button text for all items

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the adapterPosition of the item clicked to the dialog, and on pressing OK, you can call a function inside your RecyclerView adapter to update the given item.

```
updateItem(position: Int) {
   Object item = list.get(position)
   item.isVerified = true
   notifyItemChanged(position)
}
```

Make sure you call `notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)` in the adapter after you have updated the list item, this will automatically update the item at the clicked position.